# While loop to find a running total

Tags: objective-c, while-loop

I am trying to run a simple while loop to demonstrate to some pupils. The exercise is to be able to put numbers into a text box, press a button and the running total is shown in a label. The loop would be broken if the user put in the number 999. Below is my current attempt. The program will load but when the button is pressed nothing happens. Sigh!

Below is my current attempt.

```
- (IBAction)btnCalculate:(id)sender
{
    int Total, Number;

    Total = 0;
    Number= 0;

    while (Number!=999)
    {
        Number = [self.txtNumber.text integerValue];
        Total = Total + Number;
        self.lblTotal.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Total];
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Without knowing the language, I would just guess that your while loop is only being executed for the line directly after it, causing an endless loop. Maybe you need to add some kind of grouping, maybe { } around everything that should be executed in the while loop.

Comment: Looking at this a little more, i'm not sure a while loop is what you need. I'm guessing it should be an if, and if it equals 999, then exit the program. What language is this?

Comment: Hello Bob, sorry I should have mentioned this, I am using Xcode. Yes an IF statement may well suffice, I was hoping to use this exercise to show how a while loop works.

Comment: Also `Total` and `Number` are local variables, and will be re-initialized to `0` each time the button is pressed!

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect to happen?
I think the loop is blocking your main thread, so you don't see everything happen and cannot change the labels text.

I think for your purpose it would be better to read the number from the label and increase total until it has the value of number.

```
NSInteger number = [self.txtNumber.text integerValue];
while(total <= number) {
    NSLog("%d", total++);
}
```

If you want to put it in lblTotal you should run the loop on a background thread, but make sure to update your lbltotal.test on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

looks like an infinite loop to me.  The method is likely called when you click the button, and the integer value you get doesn't change in subsequent loop iterations (because you don't allow the UI thread to continue to do its thing).  You'll need to move the state out into properties on the object.  This is not like reading input from stdin.  The execution flow should go through the entire OS event loop, and your while loop is not at all part of that.  So if the first value you enter is not 999, you get stuck in the while loop and the value you get after subsequent iterations in the while loop does not change (because your while loop is the only thing running on the UI thread and it's blocking further interactivity).

Really, you need to think about the flow of control.  it's not at all like a standard terminal input / output model.